# Sails + Braintree : Unable to send the transactions details to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, braintree

I'm developing an application using `Sails JS` and `Braintree`. I'm trying to send the all past transaction details that the customer has made.

**Here is my getTransaction action**

```
getTransaction: function(req, res) {
    var customerId = req.param('customerId');
    var gateway = setUpGateway();
    var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function(search) {
        search.customerId().is(customerId);
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
        }          

        res.send(response);
    });
},
```

But the problem is, if I directly send the response which I got from braintree server, it throws the `circular dependency error`. So, to overcome that error I'm fetching only those details that I need from response like this

```
getTransaction: function(req, res) {
        var customerId = req.param('customerId');
        var gateway = setUpGateway();
        var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function(search) {
            search.customerId().is(customerId);
        }, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                return res.serverError(err);
            }

            var transactions = [];
            response.each(function(err, transaction) {
                var temp = [];

                temp.push(transaction.id);
                temp.push(transaction.amount);
                temp.push(transaction.createdAt);
                transactions.push(temp);
            });

            res.send(transactions);
        });
    },
```

But here the `.each` function is getting executed asynchronously  and hence `res.send` returns the empty array. So what should I do to return all the transaction that the user has made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

You are correct that the iterator executes asynchronously. You should use Node's stream semantics to process the request

```
getTransaction: function(req, res) {
  var customerId = req.param('customerId');
  var gateway = setUpGateway();
  var transactions = [];

  var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function(search) {
    search.customerId().is(customerId);
  });

  stream.on('data', function (transaction) {
    transactions.push(transaction);
  });

  stream.on('end', function () {
    res.send(transactions);
  });
},
```

This will wait until all transactions have been processed before sending the result.

[This page](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/searching/search-results/node) provides more information about searching using our Node client library and Node's Stream API.